# Karate UI cross browser examples

Tags: karate

Does someone have any examples of how to run cross browser UI tests in karate? I know from Peter's twitter feed that its possible but anyone having some examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this example: [`test-01.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/driver/core/test-01.feature)

It is a `Scenario Outline` and each row changes the value of `* configure driver = config`, see the `Examples` at the end:

```
Examples:
    | config |
    | { type: 'chrome' } |
    | { type: 'chromedriver' } |
    | { type: 'geckodriver' } |
```

Another strategy could be to re-run the test with different values of `karate.env` or use `call` and loop over a second feature file.